# Does GWT designer currently work with UIBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-designer

I recently learned about GWT Designer and I am trying to use it in one
of my projects.  When I tried to open myView.java I got a message that
this view is associated with a UIBinder file and that I should open
the UIBinder file.  When I open the UIBinder file I am told that I
need version 2.1 M4 for UIBinder to work.  I then install 2.1RC1 and I
get an internal error when I try and open a UI file with
windowBuilder.  So does UIBinder work with GWT Designer? If it does,
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try using the latest GWT Designer 8.1 build...

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/download-gwtdesigner-beta.html

It works much better with UiBinder than the 8.0 release from a month ago.